# OOP Python - Answer = None when calling method from child class

Tags: overriding

when I try to subtract two digits, everything goes fine but my answer is always **None** and I can't seem to solve this. Result = **None**

How can I perform subtraction under the child class and get the answer rather than None.

```
import math

class Calc_1:
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2

    def add(self):
        return self.num1 + self.num2

    def subtract(self):
        return self.num1 - self.num2

    def decide(self, choice):
        if choice == 1:
            return self.add()
        if choice == 2:
            return self.subtract()

class Calc_2(Calc_1): 
    def __init__(self, num1=None, num2=None):  
      
        super().__init__(num1, num2)
    

#subtracting

print("1. Add multiple numbers")
print("2. Subtraction")
print("3. Find Cosine")
print("4. Find Sine")
print("5. Quit","\n")

choice = input("Please make your choice: ")
print()


a = float(input("Enter first num: "))
b = float(input("Enter second num: "))

subtracting = Calc_2(a,b)

result = subtracting.decide(choice)

print ("{} - {} = ".format(subtracting.num1,subtracting.num2), result)
```

Comment: Check the type of `choice`. Does it match what you're checking against inside of `decide`?

Comment: Changed Choice to int.. still returning None. I understand that the problem is coming from the --decide-- method in the parent class

Comment: I just tried it with the modification and it works fine. Did you assign the result of `int` back to a variable? It doesn't modify the argument that you give it; it returns new data. `choice = int(input("Please make your choice: "))`.

Comment: Thanks it works. However, when I try to add new choices to a new method inside the Child class, the None returns.

class Calc_2(Calc_1): 
    def __init__(self, num1=None, num2=None):  
      
        super().__init__(num1, num2)

    def decide(self, choice):
        
        if choice==3:
            return math.cosine(self.num1)

        if choice==4:
            return math.sine(self.num1)

I haven't written the code for sine and cosine yet, but isn't it supposed to call the subtract method from the Parent class when I choose option 2? why is it continuing to give me None?

Comment: No, that's not how it works. If you override a method in the child class, only the child method will be called. If you want to call the parent's method as well, you need to call it manually yourself inside of the child method.

Comment: yeah , by using super. Again, still not working. ** super().decide(choice)

Comment: And are you returning the result of the call to the parent method?

Comment: if choice==2:
            return self.subtract()

I've added that to the Child class. it works now. What tickles me is I don't understand why it works now. I just wrote the same thing as in my Parent class in side the child class. why does it not call the subtract method automatically from the Parent class :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230768/discussion-between-krys-tof-and-carcigenicate).